# Insert into a table conditionally using values from another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a good idea of the pseudo-logic of what I want to do - just struggling to think of the syntax to put it into practice.

I’ve got three tables:
`product_images`
`product`
`product_import`

At a high level - I want to insert a row into the `product_images` table with just two values (`image_url`, `product_id`) - the `image url` can be found in the `product_import` table along with an `product_id`. This `product_id` is the old ID of the product (migrating from another system) - this is recorded as `old_id` in the product table.
Therefore the retrieval of the image_url works conditionally on the basis that: the `product_id` in the `product_import` table has a match with the old_id value in the product table. If it does match - then insert the value of the matching `image_url` from the `product_import` table and the new `product_id` that matches from the `product` table (if the `old_id` is found)

My guess at the SQL statement is something along the lines of:

```sql
INSERT INTO product_image(image_url, product_id)
SELECT product_import.image_url, product.id WHERE product.old_id = product_import.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to write an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement, the first rule is to start by designing the `SELECT ...` part.
In your case, the select query is syntactically invalid because it is missing a `FROM` statement.

So a valid select would be something like:

```
SELECT product_import.image_url, product.id
FROM product_import
INNER JOIN product ON product.old_id = product_import.id;
```

You may have to tweak it a bit based on your needs but it is the minimum query to start working. And of course you add the `INSERT` part only when you are satisfied with your `SELECT` query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - this got me on the right track. I've included my answer that worked below.

Answer (score 0):

This was what I needed in the end..

```sql
INSERT INTO product_images(image_url, product_id, account_id, is_thumbnail, created_at, modified_at)
SELECT `value`, id, account_id, "1", now(), now()
FROM product_import
JOIN product ON product_import.entity_id = product.old_id
WHERE product.account_id=1;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).